# How can I return multiple incomplete types in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C and trying out Tensorflow in C. I could see most of the Structs are incomplete type and I want to write a function where they are intialized. For example, below code is not working.

```
int main()
{
   TF_Status* Status = NULL;
   TF_Graph* Graph = NULL;
   init(Status);
   return 0;
}

void init(TF_Status* Status, TF_Graph* Graph)
{
   Status = TF_NewStatus();
   Graph = TF_NewGraph();
}
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: You passed one pointer, by value. That means that `init()` gets _a copy of_ `Status`. It knows that `Status` was NULL at the time it was called. It doesn't know where `Status` lives in memory, so it can't change the value. 
You want to pass two pointers, by reference, so that `init()` can change the pointers defined in `main()`. That's what @mikecat answer is doing

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply do `TF_Status* Status = TF_NewStatus();` Too easy, too efficient, too readable?

Comment: The reason is I want to have a initialise function which does all this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass pointers to what to modify to functions to let functions modify them.

```
void init(TF_Status** Status, TF_Graph** Graph);

int main(void)
{
   TF_Status* Status = NULL;
   TF_Graph* Graph = NULL;
   init(&Status, &Graph);
   return 0;
}

void init(TF_Status** Status, TF_Graph** Graph)
{
   *Status = TF_NewStatus();
   *Graph = TF_NewGraph();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was playing with & and ** but didnt do *Status or *Graph.